# What might this be: New Active Record chainable query language built on top of relational algebra?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3

I saw this [on a blog today](http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2010/2/5/rails-3-0-beta-release), and I thought, finally! Rails will have something like [HQL](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html) or [Linq](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_Integrated_Query). Um, or not. I couldn't find anything about this.

**What I really want to know:** will I be able to forget what the tables are called and use the object names only? Can I finally forget join syntax? I'd like to do that before I start forgetting everything else (life goals).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I understand, this means that you can write your complex queries not as

```
Object.find(:all, :conditions = > { :limit => 10, :offset => 5 }
```

but more readable way

```
Object.all.limit(10).offset(5)
```

Comment: One of the benefits of this is that it doesn't evaluate the expression until you ask for the contents.  So that won't execute ANY SQL until you iterate over it.  It's going to make caching a lot simpler.

Comment: Another point is that you can create a variable with Object.find(:all).limit(10) in controller and iterate over pages with assigning a .offset(10) on each page in view only. This make view controller logic simplier

Comment: Thanks Vestel, that's a nice addition too.

Comment: Why is that good? Apart of other reasons mentioned earlier in comments, it is also more readable and easier to write. Personaly I don't like to pass many parameters as hash - very easly it's getting very ugly.

Comment: Object.find(:all… has been old school for a long time now. Nowadays we do Object.all etc.

Answer (score 1):

Chainable queries with lazy evaluation and the AREL syntax:

This lets you write various scopes representing conditions and then mix and match them and chain them together... in the knowledge the the query will not actually get run until the output is needed ('lazy evaluation').

The syntax of AREL is much closer to standard sql syntax instead of the previous 'rails' syntax so it is easier to use and recognize and maintain for those famiiar with SQL.

Comment: Thanks. If you wanted to add any links to your answer, that would be great. Also: are people actually using this? Examples?

Answer (score 0):

You can read more about it [here](http://m.onkey.org/2010/1/22/active-record-query-interface). I'm not terribly familiar with LINQ, but I believe LINQ is somewhat similar to the query interface used by Django's ORM. At any rate, the gist is that the query interface in Active Record is more like that of Django that it was before. A lot of the older "low-level" query methods are deprecated and will be removed in later versions.

Comment: I had actually seen that article, but the question is: so? They've changed a lot. Anything good coming out of this?

Comment: Well, if you think a chainable query language is a good thing, then yeah, something good is coming out of this.

Comment: Sorry, what's the difference between chaining queries and performing queries out of the ActiveRecords returned, as we did before?